# Dividing complex rows of dataframe to simple rows in Pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have this code:

```
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext, Row

sc = SparkContext()
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)
documents = sqlContext.createDataFrame([
    Row(id=1, title=[Row(value=u'cars', max_dist=1000)]),
    Row(id=2, title=[Row(value=u'horse bus',max_dist=50), Row(value=u'normal bus',max_dist=100)]),
    Row(id=3, title=[Row(value=u'Airplane', max_dist=5000)]),
    Row(id=4, title=[Row(value=u'Bicycles', max_dist=20),Row(value=u'Motorbikes', max_dist=80)]),
    Row(id=5, title=[Row(value=u'Trams', max_dist=15)])])

documents.show(truncate=False)
#+---+----------------------------------+
#|id |title                             |
#+---+----------------------------------+
#|1  |[[1000,cars]]                     |
#|2  |[[50,horse bus], [100,normal bus]]|
#|3  |[[5000,Airplane]]                 |
#|4  |[[20,Bicycles], [80,Motorbikes]]  |
#|5  |[[15,Trams]]                      |
#+---+----------------------------------+
```

I need to split all compound rows (e.g. 2 & 4) to multiple rows while retaining the 'id', to get a result like this:

```
#+---+----------------------------------+
#|id |title                             |
#+---+----------------------------------+
#|1  |[1000,cars]                       |
#|2  |[50,horse bus]                    |
#|2  |[100,normal bus]                  |
#|3  |[5000,Airplane]                   |
#|4  |[20,Bicycles]                     |
#|4  |[80,Motorbikes]                   |
#|5  |[15,Trams]                        |
#+---+----------------------------------+
```

Comment: I don't have time to write out an answer (sorry!), but here is the idea I was building: get the ID into each element in the "title" category (say by making each compound row contain `value`,`max_dist`, and `id`), then perform a `flatMap`. You won't be able to use a `map` because `map` expects a 1-to-1 relationship between inputs and outputs. If I have time later will flesh out an answer!

Comment: Thanks @Katya Handler, I'll try your idea . if I couldn't, I would ask your help by a comment :-)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Just `explode` it:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import explode

documents.withColumn("title", explode("title"))
## +---+----------------+
## | id|           title|
## +---+----------------+
## |  1|     [1000,cars]|
## |  2|  [50,horse bus]|
## |  2|[100,normal bus]|
## |  3| [5000,Airplane]|
## |  4|   [20,Bicycles]|
## |  4| [80,Motorbikes]|
## |  5|      [15,Trams]|
## +---+----------------+
```

Comment: This is a much better answer @K.Ali

Comment: one more question @zero323 please, is it also possible to explode the resulting column 'title' vertically by the fields of the struct (col_1=1000, col_2='cars' and so on) ?

Comment: @K.Ali It is just a simple select (`select("title.value", "title.max_dist")`).

Comment: @zero323 Imagine you want to do more `explode` on the result. The goal is two have two columns one for numbers `title_num` and the other `title_type`.  What else should be added to `documents.withColumn("title", explode("title"))`? Are two explodes needed for such a task?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, here is what I've come up with. Unfortunately, I had to leave the world of `Row` objects and enter the world of `list` objects because I couldn't find a way to `append` to a `Row` object.

That means this method is bit messy. If you can find a way to add a new column to a `Row` object, then this is NOT the way to go.

```
def add_id(row):
    it_list = []
    for i in range(0, len(row[1])):
        sm_list = []
        for j in row[1][i]:
            sm_list.append(j)
        sm_list.append(row[0])
        it_list.append(sm_list)
    return it_list

with_id = documents.flatMap(lambda x: add_id(x))

df = with_id.map(lambda x: Row(id=x[2], title=Row(value=x[0], max_dist=x[1]))).toDF()
```

When I run `df.show()`, I get:

```
+---+----------------+
| id|           title|
+---+----------------+
|  1|     [cars,1000]|
|  2|  [horse bus,50]|
|  2|[normal bus,100]|
|  3| [Airplane,5000]|
|  4|   [Bicycles,20]|
|  4| [Motorbikes,80]|
|  5|      [Trams,15]|
+---+----------------+
```

Comment: If I may suggest: `def flatten(row): id_, items = row; return ((id_, item) for item in items)` followed by `documents.rdd.flatMap(flatten).toDF(["id", "title"])`.

Comment: Thanks again @Katya Handler, I liked your raw idea :-)

Answer (score 0):

I am using Spark Dataset API, and following solved the 'explode' requirement for me:

```
Dataset<Row> explodedDataset = initialDataset.selectExpr("ID","explode(finished_chunk) as chunks");
```

**Note**: The explode method of Dataset API is deprecated in Spark 2.4.5 and the documentation suggests using Select(shown above) or FlatMap.