# select at most first 3 elements in a row after splitting

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe

i have a dataframe in spark :

```
Col_A | Col_B
--------------
  A    |    1,6,5,3,7      
  B    |   17,18,78     
  C    |    90  
  D    |    56,57
```

both `Col_A` and `Col_B` are of string type.

how can i select  (at most) first 3 elements (or only 1 or 2 if there is less than 3 elements) after splitting a particular row by the delimiter `(",")` and convert the above data frame to
new data frame below :

```
Col_A  |  Col_B
----------------    
A      |  1    
A      |  6    
A      |  5    
B      |  17    
B      |  18    
B      |  78    
C      |   90    
D      |   56
D      |   57
```

here also both `col_A` and `col_B` are of string type.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: You need [explode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36186627/dividing-complex-rows-of-dataframe-to-simple-rows-in-pyspark) + [Window function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38397796/retrieve-top-n-in-each-group-of-a-dataframe-in-pyspark)

Answer (score 1):

You can write a simple `udf` that `splits` the `String` and returns at most 3 values from `array` as

```
val origDF = Seq(
  ("A", "1,6,5,3,7"),
  ("B", "17,18,78"),
  ("C", "90"),
  ("D", "56,57")
).toDF("Col_A", "Col_B")

val valueAsArray = udf((value: String) => {
  value.split(",").map(_.trim).take(3)
})
```

Now use the `udf` with `withColumn` and `explode`

```
origDF.withColumn("Col_B", explode(valueAsArray($"Col_B"))).show(false)
```

Output:

```
+-----+-----+
|Col_A|Col_B|
+-----+-----+
|A    |1    |
|A    |6    |
|A    |5    |
|B    |17   |
|B    |18   |
|B    |78   |
|C    |90   |
|D    |56   |
|D    |57   |
+-----+-----+
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve your final required dataframe using `maps` and `flatMaps` as

```
//get the column names
val columns = df.columns
//transform the dataframe using dataset way
df.flatMap(row => row.getAs[String]("Col_B").trim.split(",").take(3).map(value => (row.getAs[String]("Col_A"), value))).toDF(columns: _*).show(false)
```

which should give you

```
+-----+-----+
|Col_A|Col_B|
+-----+-----+
|A    |1    |
|A    |6    |
|A    |5    |
|B    |17   |
|B    |18   |
|B    |78   |
|C    |90   |
|D    |56   |
|D    |57   |
+-----+-----+
```