# parse values from list in dataframe column

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I have a pyspark dataframe like the input dataframe below.  It has a column colA that contains lists of numbers as each value.  I would like to create a new column colC that parses each number from the list in colA, like the example output dataframe below.  Can anyone suggest how to do this?

input dataframe:

```
colA    colB
[1,2]   1
[3,2,4] 2
```

output dataframe:

```
colA    colB colC
[1,2]   1    1
[1,2]   1    2
[3,2,4] 2    3
[3,2,4] 2    2
[3,2,4] 2    4
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dividing complex rows of dataframe to simple rows in Pyspark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36186627/dividing-complex-rows-of-dataframe-to-simple-rows-in-pyspark)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be done by `explode` function:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import explode

df.withColumn("colC", explode(df.colA)).show()
```

Output:

```
+---------+----+----+
|     colA|colB|colC|
+---------+----+----+
|   [1, 2]|   1|   1|
|   [1, 2]|   1|   2|
|[3, 2, 4]|   2|   3|
|[3, 2, 4]|   2|   2|
|[3, 2, 4]|   2|   4|
+---------+----+----+
```