# Explode column values into multiple columns in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have the following pyspark dataframe.

```
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|substitutes                                                                     |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|[[1, 30981733]]                                                                 |
|[[1, 598319049], [2, 38453298], [3, 2007569845]]                                |
|[[1, 10309216]]                                                                 |
|[[1, 730446111], [2, 617024811], [3, 665689309], [4, 883699488], [5, 159896736]]|
|[[1, 10290923], [2, 33282357]]                                                  |
|[[1, 102649381], [2, 10294853], [3, 10294854], [4, 44749181], [5, 35132896]]    |
|[[1, 10307642], [2, 10307636], [3, 15754215], [4, 45612359], [5, 10307635]]     |
|[[1, 43982130], [2, 15556050], [3, 15556051], [4, 11961012], [5, 16777263]]     |
|[[1, 849607426], [2, 185158834], [3, 11028011], [4, 10309801], [5, 11028010]]   |
|[[1, 21905160], [2, 21609422], [3, 21609417], [4, 20554612], [5, 20554601]]     |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

And I would like to explode the columns into multiple columns

```
| substitutes_1 | substitutes_2 | substitutes_3 | substitutes_4 | substitutes_5 |
|---------------|---------------|---------------|---------------|---------------|
| 30981733      |               |               |               |               |
| 598319049     | 38453298      | 2007569845    |               |               |
| 10309216      |               |               |               |               |
| 730446111     | 617024811     | 665689309     | 883699488     | 159896736     |
| 10290923      | 33282357      |               |               |               |
| 102649381     | 10294853      | 10294854      | 44749181      | 35132896      |
| 10307642      | 10307636      | 15754215      | 45612359      | 10307635      |
| 43982130      | 15556050      | 15556051      | 11961012      | 16777263      |
| 849607426     | 185158834     | 11028011      | 10309801      | 11028010      |
| 21905160      | 21609422      | 21609417      | 20554612      | 20554601      |
```

How can i unpivot and explode the array?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dividing complex rows of dataframe to simple rows in Pyspark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36186627/dividing-complex-rows-of-dataframe-to-simple-rows-in-pyspark)

Comment: No @AntrikshChourasia

Comment: every row have one or  multiple sub arrays . I want a new column for every sub array for that row. with subarray[0] as column name and subarray[1] as its value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a temporary `id` column for uniquely identifying each row. Explode the `substitutes` then extract the first item as `col` and second item as `val`. Then group the dataframe by `id`, `pivot` on `col` and aggregate `val` with first

```
(
    df
    .withColumn('id', F.monotonically_increasing_id())
    .selectExpr('id', "explode(substitutes) AS S")
    .selectExpr('id', "'substitutes_' || S[0] AS col", "S[1] as val")
    .groupby('id').pivot('col').agg(F.first('val'))
    .drop('id')
)
```

Result

```
+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
|substitutes_1|substitutes_2|substitutes_3|substitutes_4|substitutes_5|
+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
|    598319049|     38453298|   2007569845|         null|         null|
|     30981733|         null|         null|         null|         null|
|    102649381|     10294853|     10294854|     44749181|     35132896|
|    849607426|    185158834|     11028011|     10309801|     11028010|
|     10307642|     10307636|     15754215|     45612359|     10307635|
|    730446111|    617024811|    665689309|    883699488|    159896736|
|     10290923|     33282357|         null|         null|         null|
|     43982130|     15556050|     15556051|     11961012|     16777263|
|     10309216|         null|         null|         null|         null|
|     21905160|     21609422|     21609417|     20554612|     20554601|
+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
```